# nested array document find by key mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have document which contains array named items on inside document which contains 3 location 1st location - mumbai 2nd - london
End 3rd - Delhi and all of them their famous street

{

```
"id": "1",
"category": "education",
"field": "science",
"items": [
  {
    "location": "mumbai",
    "street": "Marine Drive"
  },
  {
    "location": "mumbai",
    "street": "Linking Road"
  },
  {
    "location": "london",
    "street": "Oxford Street"
  },
  {
    "location": "mumbai",
    "street": "Bruce Street"
  },
  {
    "location": "delhi",
    "street": "Chandni Chowk"
  },
  {
    "location": "london",
    "street": "Carnaby Street"
  },
  {
    "location": "london",
    "street": "King's Road"
  },
  
]
```

}

using mongodb aggregation in nodejs
i want only  2 street name at a time through limit(). in  all  of location
expected output

{

```
"items": [
  {
    "location": "mumbai",
    "street": [
      "Marine Drive",
      "Linking Road",
    
    ]
  },
  {
    "location": "london",
    "street": [
      "Oxford Street",
      "Carnaby Street"
    ]
  },
  {
    
    "location": "delhi",
    "street": [
      "Chandni Chowk",
    ]
  }
]
```

}

please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please see code and help

Answer (score 0):

If you created a schema for the 'item' object in node using mongoose, you can specify in the schema the structure you want. For example:

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: String
  },
  streets: [{
      type: String,
      validate:{
           validator: function(v,x,z) {
          return !(this.streets.length > 2);  
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} exceeds maximum capacity of 2` 
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

The validator function is something I pulled from another user's answer in these question: [Mongoose schema: how to set max number of items in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175684/mongoose-schema-how-to-set-max-number-of-items-in-an-array)

Comment: In database  unlimited  streets but i want limiting through aggregation

Comment: Oh then use the $limit aggregation, here are the docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/